# How to check a code with the current device's lock code

Tags: android, security

I am creating an Android app in which the user must enter a code to use an action (Eg. Pay, add card etc. ).

Instead of implementing my own custom code, is there a way for me to verify if the entered code is the same code to unlock the device and if yes then allow, if not then dont allow.

I was not able to find the solution for this.

Comment: There may be a way to use the fingerprint scanner for devices that have one (and if the user has set it up).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way for me to verify if the entered code is the same code to unlock the device

No. From a security standpoint, that would be horrible, as it would allow you to brute-force determine what the user's PIN or passphrase is. Also note that users do not necessarily use a PIN or passphrase to lock their device (e.g., use a fingerprint).

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks for the answer.